# How can I make the Mylyn GitHub Connector for Eclipse run authenticated requests?

Tags: eclipse, oauth, github, egit, mylyn

I'm using the very cool [Github Mylyn Connector](https://github.com/blog/852-github-mylyn-connector-for-eclipse) for [Eclipse Indigo](https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=eclipse%20indigo&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://www.eclipse.org/indigo/&ei=DVDrUNr2DsKctQaryoGYCA&usg=AFQjCNHDQcWhz9GRBeUv0BKil66TSfSsdQ&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.Yms). However, since I use it for many projects on GitHub, I run very quickly into the 60 requests per second [rate limit](http://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting) enforced on unauthenticated requests against the GitHub v3 API.

The Symptom is that refreshing any query (however small — again, the limiting factor here is more that I deal with may repositories) I get the error:

```
Unexpected error : API Rate Limit Exceeded for XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

Where `XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX` is of course my IP.

I have configured the GitHub repositories in the Task Repository View with my GitHub username and password, but the connector doesn't seem to make use of those for either OAuth or Basic Authentication. I have read the [FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/GitHub/UserGuide) of the GitHub connector plugin and haven't found anything of use there.

Is there a way to get the GitHub connector to make authenticated requests (that would count against the much more relaxed rate limit of 5K/hour ?) ?

---

Edit: I have tried with a private repository (which has at least one active issue) to check whether *some* credentials were sent there. I got `Unexpected error: Issues are disabled for this repo`.

---

Edit: I noticed the problem with the version of the plugin on the Eclipse Marketplace, then switched to getting my EGit plugin from the [nightlies repo](http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates-nightly), and likewise for the [Mylyn Github Connector](http://download.eclipse.org/egit/github/updates-nightly). It didn't help

Comment: Do you have the "Save Password" option enabled for the repositories in the Task Repositories view?

Comment: Yes. "Anonymous" is unchecked, "Save Password" is checked.

Comment: Intercept the network calls that goes out of Eclipse using some tools like `Fiddler` and see if there are any unncessary calls.  You may close unnecessary projects in Eclipse or use Working Sets.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse Neon with Mylyn Github connector 4.4.

Tested with [2-factor access token](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use/). Anonymous rate limit successfully exceeded on a public repository with hundreds of issues.  I did not test with simple login but it should work.